# DuplicateResult Class where are fields added from?

Tags: apex

I am using DuplicateResult Class to capture and display duplicate records. I am using this code snippet from the documentation:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Datacloud_DuplicateResult.htm
My question is, what indicates what fields from the Contact object are included the matchRecord array? Is it the duplicate rules that define the fields for the query? 
I am attempting to add additional fields from the Contact object but get an error:

> SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested
>   field: Account.State

Comment: there is no field Account.State - there is Account.BillingState or Account.ShippingState

Comment: Thank you for catching that. I meant to say I can not access Account.BillingState, but yet I am able to access Account.BillingStreet.

Comment: Do you have state and country pick lists enabled?

Comment: No, the billingState and billingCountry are strings.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the specific fields you have in your compact layout?

Answer (score 2):

It uses the object's primary CompactLayout.  See the [`findDuplicates()` documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_findduplicates.htm).

> If the includeRecordDetails flag in DuplicateRuleHeader is set to
>   false, findDuplicates() only returns the record IDs of the matching
>   records. Otherwise, findDuplicates() returns all the fields specified
>   in the primary CompactLayout associated with the target object

Comment: Thank you for the info. I have address field added in the compact layout. I am able to access Street, but get the error, when I try accessing state.

Comment: I'm guessing that `findDuplicates()` will retrieve only the base object fields, not related object fields.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I am trying to get the base object fields. That is why I am confused as to why I can access the billing street, but not billing State. I thought this must be configured somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured it out.Under the DuplicateResult class there is a method called Datacloud.match. This method identifies the matching or different fields defined in the Matching Rule/Matching criteria. In other words, the only fields returned by the Duplicateresults are fields that are defined in the rules. You can not return a field which is not part of it. I included BillingState in the matching rules, and now I am able to access it.